# ListBox очень долго иницилизируется с большим количеством элементов

Tags: yandex-maps-api, listbox

Здравсвуйте

При создании [ListBox](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.ListBox-docpage/) содержащий около 1000 элементов, его инициализация занимает более 30 секунд, при этом подвешивая интерфейс (вероятно из-за однопоточности javascript).

Может быть есть способы ускорить инициализацию или использовать какие-то другие элементы интерфейса для реализации выпадающего списка?

Пример кода (можно попробовать в [песочнице](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/list_box_layout)):

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 9,
            controls: []
        }),

        // Создадим 1000 пунктов выпадающего списка
        listBoxItems = [...Array(1000).keys()].map(function(n) {
            return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                    data: {
                        content: n
                    }
                })
            })

        // Теперь создадим список
        listBox = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
                items: listBoxItems,
                data: {
                    content: 'Выберите пункт'
                }
        });          


    myMap.controls.add(listBox, {float: 'left'});
}
```

Comment: 1000 элементов списка это издевательство и над пользователем и над браузером

Comment: А какие альтернативы, когда имеется 1300 номеров объектов и для дальнейшей обработки надо выбрать несколько или все?

Comment: например так, как на этом ресурсе организован выбор тегов, при создании вопроса

Comment: Пользователь не знает какие номера могут быть.
Из идей, приходит в голову двухуровневый список, когда в одном списке выбираешь начало номера, во втором списке отображается все что подходит под выбранный шаблон первого списка. + один из пунктов выбрать все.
Только это не защищает от 1000+ элементов во втором списке..

Comment: тогда как выдаче поиска, страницами, прогрессивная загрузка на худой конец

Comment: Как вариант, но тогда это уже не чистый YandexMaps JS API, надо чем то оборачивать, т.е. переписывать все с нуля, хотелось бы отделаться малой кровью.

Comment: ну Вы все верно поняли

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox` не рассчитан на такие объемы. Возьмите любой готовый dropdown с фильтрацией, например [Choices](https://joshuajohnson.co.uk/Choices/), и напишите свой контрол, это довольно просто ([пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control) есть в песочнице).

Comment: Спасибо, видимо больше ничего не остается, если пользоваться только Y.Maps JS API, без обертки.